# How to implement one to many with jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I'm trying to write a program to manage some clients. Each client has reservations, and each reservation has items.I  know that I have one to many relationship, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

I'm not using Spring, only JDBC.

Without a database I did it like that:

```
public class Client {

    private String _fullName;
    private String _address;
    private String _email;
    private String _phoneNumber;
    private List<Reservation> _reservations;
    }

public class Reservation {

    private List<Item> _items;
    private int _totalSum;
    private boolean _toDeliver;
    private String _date;
}
public class Item {

    //primary key.
    private int _id;
    private int _price;
    private String _name;

}
```

Do I have to declare these Lists? Is it possible to do that without Spring, Hibernate and other stuff? I just want to know how design my program.

Comment: By the way, no need to mark your member fields with leading underscores. Modern editors will colorize your code to so indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do everything just with a JDBC database driver.

The first thing you have to do is to design your database, that is your tables and constraints and etc.

Then you go back to Java and query your database using the JDBC.

A common approach to this is creating a DAO class, where you can decouple your database query from your code. It goes something like this:

```
public String getUserName(String userId) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE user_id = ?";

    try (Connection connection = getConnection();
         PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        stmt.setString(1, userId);

        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a simple example, there's no error handling here, neither dealing with empty query results, there are better examples online to illustrate how to make a DAO and create a connection. Depending on where you are running this code, you would prefer using a Connection Pool for efficiency (another thing to read more about).

In your use case, you would have the DAO get the data to make your `Item`, create a new `Item` and return it from the DAO. There are plenty of examples of this online, if you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: first of all , thanks!!
i think my problem its about how to make the tables
do i have to declare primary key to client and foreign key to his reservation ? and by the key of client i get access to his reservations?

what if i want to read the items from file and save them into the DB (what i actually did)  and display a menu to the user to pick some items,do i have to make reservation object in java? or only to get to client table and by his key to add new reservation.

maybe i have to read more about how to do that,i tried to find example for my issue,but i didnt find.
thank you !!

Comment: What you want to do is not something simple that I can answer in one simple answer, you are dealing with a system that has to collect data from the user (UI), transform into something the Database will accept and send it to the Database. It's a multi-tier application. You have to read more about Database relations, 0-to-1, 1-to-1, 1-to-many, many-to-1, many-to-many etc. Then you will understand how to manipulate your database from code, as you will know which tables to update when the user does some action. I cannot build it all for you from here.